# AWS S3 CLI sync command free define time period configure

Tags: batch-file, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have .bat file inside that calls the AWS sync command:

```
aws s3 sync D:\Users\backup s3://mybucket
```

It syncs my local data to an S3 bucket. Then I created a Windows Scheduler Task for that .bat file, and every day at 2300hr the .bat file start to run and syncs my local data to the S3 bucket.

some time I have big data inside backup file. so i want to give particular time period to run `aws s3 sync` (example sync run only `1300hr to 0100hr`)

note: if sync stop without all data sync next day should be resume sync at 1300hr

I have two questions:

1. How can i force stop sync data given time period?
2. If i have big data(more than 100GB) AWS CLI power enough to efficiently sync data ?

Comment: What is your question/problem? Are you saying that the `sync` fails if there is too much data? Or are you saying that you want to force the sync to stop if it continues for more than a certain length of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always **kill** the "rsync" task in Task Scheduler if it runs longer than 1,2,4,8 12 hours/days/etc.

Simply go to task properties in Task Scheduler and click on 'Settings" tab, you will see a checkbox "Stop the task if it runs longer than:" (select whatever value you want)

You would then be chipping away at your 100GB of files each night you run it.